# how to make calls from my cell number, while using my laptop as the "headset"?

Tags: calls, google-voice, voip

I want to be able to dial out from my laptop (a macbook pro), using my laptop headset to communicate and my laptop to initiate the call, however I want the number to be the same as my  cell phone's (Galaxy S4). I can get almost exactly what I want from Gmail / Hangouts, however the call does not show up as my cellphone (a number friends and family recognize) but instead as a number they do not recognize.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you using google voice? That is, do your friends and family know your "google voice" number, or your "actual cell" number? I see that the question is marked with the google-voice tag, but you don't mention it in your question.

Comment: It might be possible to connect your phone and laptop via the Bluetooth HFP profile for audio, and some control. Then use an app such a MightyText to initiate the call.

Answer (score 1):

[VoiceMac](https://mrgeckosmedia.com/applications/info/VoiceMac) makes calls and SMSes via Google Voice. You can choose one of a GV number - which you keep, so your friends & family can recognize it - or you can [port your existing phone number into GV](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/1065667?hl=en). The incoming caller ID will show your GV number (but no name).

Another option is to use Skype and validate your cell# as your Skype caller ID.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no least possible way to Call through the Laptop(either windows or Mac) even if your headset is connected or not.(try the play store for any apps if possible)

You can only send messages through Samsung Kies Air but not Calling.

Also check for some screen cast applications that support the Mac OS X